# Grunt usemin and absolute (nonexistent) file paths

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

My directory structure looks like this, I have an absolute path `/static` mapped to my `public dir`

```
+public/
  +--app/
  +--dist/
  |--Gruntfile.js
  |..
  |..
```

Currently, everything builds fine and I wind up with my minified/rev'd files in `dist` but the `index.html` file contains relative paths like:

`<script src="some-file.56a75bad.js"></script>`

When I need them to be:

`<script src="/static/dist/some-file.56a75bad.js"></script>`

Can't seem to figure out how to achieve this, everything I've tried winds up giving my the right file paths but not the rev'd file, i.e:

`<script src="/static/dist/some-file.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

**My solution:** `copy` task moves all scripts to a `.tmp` folder. `uglify` task then runs and outputs to a folder hierarchy in `.tmp` that the absolute paths to resolve to. After those 2 tasks are run I have a folder structure that looks like this (mid build):

```
public/
  +--.tmp/
    +--static/
      +--dist/
        |--application.min.js
        |--dependencies.min.js
  +--app/
  +--bower_components/
  +--dist/
  |--Gruntfile.js
  |--index.html
```

A little piece of my `index.html`

```
<!-- build:js /static/dist/dependencies.min.js -->
<script src="/static/dist/dependencies.min.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js /static/dist/application.min.js -->
<script src="/static/dist/application.min.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Now it's business as usual, the `useminPrepare` `filerev` and `usemin` tasks are run.

And my GruntFile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.config.init({

        useminPrepare: {
            html: 'dist/index.html',
            options: {
                dest: './dist'
            }
        },

        usemin:{
            html:['dist/index.html'],
            options: {
                assetsDirs: ['.tmp']
            }
        },

        copy:{
            html: {
                src: './index.html',
                dest: 'dist/index.html'
            },
            javascripts: {
                cwd: '',
                src: 'app/scripts/**',
                dest: '.tmp',
                expand: true
            }
        },

        uglify: {
            build: {
                options: {
                    mangle: true
                },
                files: {
                    '.tmp/static/dist/application.min.js': ['.tmp/app/**/*.js'],
                    '.tmp/static/dist/dependencies.min.js': [
                        'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
                        'bower_components/angular/angular.js'
                        // All my other 3rd party libs, I realized this can be done in index.html but there's environmental constraints making that not possible
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        filerev: {
            dist: {
                src: ['.tmp/static/dist/application.min.js', '.tmp/static/dist/dependencies.min.js'],
                dest: 'dist'
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.registerTask('build',[
        'copy:javascripts',
        'copy:html',
        'uglify',
        'useminPrepare',
        'filerev',
        'usemin'
    ]);
};
```